# C#: WebRequest proxy = null side effects

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

Does anyone know what the side effects are of having a `webrequest.proxy = null` in a HttpWebRequest?

MSDN (.NET Framework 4) says to use `GlobalProxySelection.GetEmptyWebProxy()` when no proxy should be used. A blank `IWebProxy` instance will be returned. Visual Studio says it's deprecated!!

Does the webrequest in both cases still work if the user's network requires proxy settings?

*So*, what is the correct approach and any known issues/side effects when a proxy is needed?

---

About the deprecated issue; Visual Studio says: Use `null` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there are no side effects.
VS is advising you correctly.

> Does the webrequest in both cases still work if the user's network requires proxy settings?

An entirely different question. Your connection will most likely *not* work. Use  [`WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.defaultwebproxy.aspx) instead.

Comment: So, I assume the following is correct: If `WebRequest.Proxy = null` then `WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy` will be ignored.

Comment: I think so, would have to try to be sure. But is that a valid use-case?

Comment: It is a valid use case. I think the best option in my case is keeping the default settings. But, to be sure and for the knowledge I will try at my work tomorrow!

Comment: Note that in some environments, WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy may also be null.