# Entity Framework 6 does not ignore TransactionScope with enlist=false

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-6

Here is a very simplistic example of my current state:

```cs
using(var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, transactionScopeTimeout, TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled))
{
    const string ConnectionString="server=localhost;username=;password=;enlist=false;Initial Catalog=blubber"
    using(var myContext = new MyContext(ConnectionString))
    {
        var myTestObject = new TestObjectBuilder().WithId(1).Build();
        myContext.Add(myTestObject);
        myContext.SaveChanges();
    }
    // ...
    using(var myContext = new MyContext(ConnectionString))
    {
        var myObj = myContext.MyObjects.Single(s => s.Id == 1); // This is the same object as above
    }
}
```

I have a `TransactionScope` which will be used here, **but** in my connectionstring I explicitly say I don't wanna enlist my Entity Framework (6.2) Transactions.
The current behavior is that on the `Single(s => s.Id == 1)` Expression I get an error after 30 seconds (the default timeout) that the element could not be found.
First of all: Why do I not get a timeout-Exception or any SqlException? Second: Why is my data-row locked in the database?

Also via Sql Server Management Studio I can not query that exact row (only with the `NOLOCK` hint).
If I remove the `TransactionScope` or set the `ISOLATION LEVEL` to `READ UNCOMMITED` before the `Single` query everything works fine.
Also because of the `Dispose` of the transaction-scope at the end all data will be removed / rollbacked which also should not happen if I didn't enlist to this `AmbientTransaction`.

So my expected behavior is, that I get no lock and my data is persisted even the transactionscope is disposed and rollbacked. EF should ignore the transactionscope here.

Do I miss something critical here?

EDIT: I tried the same thing with `NHibernate` and here it works like a charm.

Comment: Normally the 30 second timeout is when the default is used to go to Proxy Server.    Does code work after error?  The solution is turn off the proxy server.

Comment: There is no proxy server in between. It is really localhost. And the code afterwards works fine as someone just swallows the exception

Comment: Also wrapping the two contexts with using (new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Suppress)) {} works... But EF should ignore it in the first place

Comment: Exactly.  The default setting is Proxy so code wait for 30 seconds until the proxy timeout occurs and then runs normal.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean with "default setting is Proxy"? And how to configure the connection string so no proxy is used? @jdweng

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7325572/c-webrequest-proxy-null-side-effects